# CSS / HTML compatability issues with Internet Explorer (IE)

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, compatibility

Ok, I am a game developer and I am putting together a personal portfolio website. I have some limited experience with CSS, HTML, PHP, MySQL, ect. I am just starting to delve into Jquery and some of the cool effects that are possible with it. but IE just does not want to cooperate with my menu and picture gallery. Here is what I have thus far:

http://andrewaernst.com

Everything appears to be working as it should be in FireFox and Google Chrome, but IE keeps pushing my two jquery powered elements to the far left. I have been playing with the CSS and HTML code for hours and can not figure out why IE is doing what it is doing. I am sure that someone with some web development experience will be able to point me in the right direction.

The navigation menu is from: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/16/slide-down-box-menu/

And picture gallery is using the Nivo Slider. (would link it, but since I am a new user I am limited to two links per post. It should be easy enough to find though).

I wish I could say I had it narrowed down to a specific area in the code, but I honestly have no idea what is causing the issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You stand at the edge of the deep, dark abyss that is getting things to work with all browsers (particularly IE) :(

Comment: What version of IE? 7?, 8?, 9?

Comment: Quick note: I am running IE 9.0.8 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be any number of things, but I'd start with removing the comment you have in the top of your HTML document which I *think* may prevent IE from recognizing your DOCTYPE and thus go into quirks mode.

I would then go ahead and fix the HTML errors as they can sometimes cause different rendering in different browsers: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fandrewaernst.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Edit: In IE6, for example, I get "-->" printed on the page. That's probably not intentional.

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems to have fixed it.